# Can there be more than one DOM object in the Cycle.js drivers?

Tags: cyclejs

All the Cycle.js examples I've found so far, use a single `DOM` object, named "DOM", in the `drivers` argument to `run(main, drivers)`. Is it possible to have more than one object, e.g., one named "DOM1" and another "DOM2"? The purpose of this would be to control two separate dynamic DOM areas within a single HTML page, in order to keep a third DOM area statically defined in `index.html`, and sandwiched between DOM1 and DOM2.

As a side question, the examples I've seen typically target an HTML `div` with an id of `#app` or `#main-container`, and then the sink is defined with a `@cycle/dom` `div` function, thus creating AFAICT an unnecessary `div` within a `div`. I haven't found a clear explanation or reference of how the virtual nodes are supposed to be defined. Say that DOM2 above targets an HTML `form` element and that is supposed to contain two `input` elements. Does it *have* to start with a `div` as in all the examples, or can the `input`s be defined directly in the `.map` call, and if so, how?

Comment: Here's an [ESNextbin](https://esnextb.in/?gist=b54baa4131974b7f12d190fb63be8aeb) demo of two independent DOMs.

Comment: Thanks @bloodyKnuckles. So I guess the answer is *yes*, you can have two or more DOMs. However, my question now becomes "do the DOMs *have* to be independent?" as you mentioned and as shown in the demo, or can one DOM at least passively influence the other, e.g., the input field in DOM1 and the h1 element in DOM2. I think I can experiment on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from having a `DOM1` and `DOM2` sinks in your app. bloodyKnuckles' example illustrate that perfectly https://esnextb.in/?gist=b54baa4131974b7f12d190fb63be8aeb

That being said, I am not sure I really see the point of doing this. If it's a matter of performance, I don't think you will gain much in splitting the rendering of your app into two DOMDrivers. The virtual DOM lib (in cycle's case snabbdom) is tailored to recognize pieces of DOM that haven't change from those which have and only updates the latter.

If it's a matter of responsibilities (those 2 pieces of DOM have very different purposes), then I would rather create two different cycle apps that both render in different parts of the DOM. (and then call `run` twice in your main file)

```
function app1(sources) {
  return {
    DOM: xs.of(div("hello from app1"))
  }
}


function app2(sources) {
  return {
    DOM: xs.of(div("hello from app2"))
  }
}

run(app1, {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver("#app1")
})


run(app2, {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver("#app2")
})
```

This way you have a clear separation of the concerns of both apps.

Now to answer your question about why a piece of virtual DOM needs to be wrapped in a `div`. It is because a piece of virtual DOM have to have a **single root** element. Said otherwise: a piece of virtual DOM have to be standalone (just like an HTML document only has a single `<html>` element which is the root).
It is, actually, a nice constraint to have because it forces you to have standalone components. In the example you give (with an `<input>` field), there is absolutely no problem in returning a vDOM like this:

```
DOM: xs.of(input(/*...*/))
```

But if your component has an `input` and a `label`, then you will need to wrap it in another vNode

```
DOM: xs.of(div([label(/*...*/), input(/*...*/)])
```

Comment: It's neither performance nor responsibilities. I was just reluctant to code the large static area in JavaScript (actually TypeScript). However, I've now realized the "static" area does need to be updated, so the issue of splitting the areas is moot.